Возможно ли вернуть первое не NULL значение в столбце с помощью функции COALESCE
Представим, что есть поле, N первых элементов которого, возможно, имеют неопределенное значение NULL. Разумеется, в этой же таблице должно быть поле-идентификатор, по которому мы можем таблицу отсортировать. Возможно ли каким-то образом вернуть первое не NULL значение, используя COALESCE? Возможно ли передать в COALESCE столбец как набор значений?
Как получить требующийся результат без COALESCE я понимаю. Так же я, в общем, понимаю что COALESCE нужна не для этого, а для подмены неопределенностей на определенные значения. Так что вопрос носит скорее академический характер

COALESCE работает "горизонтально". Вы хотите "вертикально" - соответственно, ответ "нет". Возможно ли передать в COALESCE столбец как набор значений? Можно преобразовать с использованием динамического SQL - но это уж больно извратно получится.

@Akina спасибо, ответ исчерпывающий.
